# How to compare a fixed value against multiple values and find if any one fails to match

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I have a fixed int value - 1050. I have around 50 dynamic values that I want to compare with the fixed value. So I compare it in a for loop. I have a public variable which I set as ok or notok depending on result. But my problem is that the value of the public variable is always the last value that I compared. Example, If I have the 20th dynamic value as 1000, it should return notok, but the value of the variable is always the last compared value. How do I set the variable to notok even if one/multiple of the values of dynamic variable doesnt match with fixed variable? I also display the total number of notok values in a listbox.

Here is what I have:

```
  string result;
  for(int i = 0; i < dynamicvalue.count; i++)
  {
    if(dynamicvalue[i] != setvalue)
    {
        result = "notok";
        listBox1.Items.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        result = "ok";
    }
   }
```

Comment: Not sure what is the data type of `dynamicvalue` but you dont compare with its elements, such as `dynamicvalue[i]`

Comment: @macroland have updated my question, forgot to add [i]. dynamicvalue are also integers.

Comment: `dynamicvalue` is some sort of collection I believe. Also `.count()` is for C# I believe.

Comment: Why `C++` tagged for this question?

Comment: You can `break` out of the loop.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar I believe this question can also be answered by the c++ community folks.

Comment: @Jimi i cannot break out of it as I have to compare all 50 dynamic values.

Comment: @Stormbringer, do you want a solution in `C#` or `C++`? This question can be answered in any language languages.

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar c#

Comment: The question is *How do I set the variable to notok even if one of the values...*. And this is what the code shows. But you probably have other code there that you didn't show (and a description of what happens after is probably required to answer the question). So, check whether `notok` has already been set. Maybe use a `bool` instead. -- If instead you just need to check whether the collection contains at least one non-matching value, then break out of it when you find one. --  Add a better description of the requirements.

Comment: @Stormbringer So basically if any of the values in `dynamicvalues` != `setvalue` then `result = "notok"` right? So you can `break` out of the loop after you do `result = "notok";`.

Comment: I have updated the question. I cannot break out of the loop. There can be one/multiple notok's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this by reading @deminalla 's answer.

I added two more integers to work as counters and after the for loop I compare the values of these integers to get the final result.

Here's what I did:

```
 string result;
 int okcounter = 0;
 int notokcounter = 0;
 for(int i = 0; i < dynamicvalue.count; i++)
 {
   if(dynamicvalue[i] != setvalue)
   {
     notokcounter ++;
     listBox1.Items.Add(notokcounter);
   }
   else
   {
     okcounter++;;
   }
 }
 if(notokcounter >=1)
 {
   result = "notok";
 }
 else if(okcounter == dynamicvalue.count)
 {
   result = "ok";
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) from Linq,

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a
> condition.

```
string result =  dynamicvalue.Any(x => x == setValue) ? "Ok" : "Not Ok";
```

---

If you want to use `for` loop without a `break` statement, you are just increasing the time complexity of your code.

I will never recommend it, but if you want you can try the below code

```
string result = "Ok";
bool flag = true;
//This for loop will iterate for n times.
for(int i = 0; i < dynamicvalue.Count; i++)
{
  if(dynamicvalue[i] != setvalue && flag)
     {
      result = "Not Ok";
      flag = false;   //flag will help us to execute this block of code only once.
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

To have `"notok"` if theres at least one not matching, one way to do it in plain code:

```
string result = "ok";
for(int i=0; i<dynamicvalue.count; ++i)
    {
      if(dynamicvalue[i] != setvalue)
         {
          result = "notok";
          break;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Hi MatG, I have updated the question. There can be one or multiple notok's. So I cannot break till I complete the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most performant way to answer this would be to keep your numbers in a HashSet instead (make `dynamicvalue` a `HashSet<int>`), then it's:

```
dynamicvalue.Contains(setvalue) ? "ok" : "notok"
```

A HashSet can much more quickly answer "do you contain this value?" than a list/array can

Answer (score 1):

By the discussion going on in the comments I'm thinking that you want to go through all the elements in dynamicvalue and check all if any of them are ok or notok. If that is the case, you should turn result into an array. You get the last compared result because each time the cycle loops, the string gets assigned a new value all over again so the previous value gets discarded.

Is this what you want to do? I wrote it in c++

```
  int setvalue = 1050;
  int notok = 0;
  int dynamicvalue[5] = {1, 2, 3, 1050, 4}; //for example
  string result[5];
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(dynamicvalue); i++){
    if (dynamicvalue[i] != setvalue){
      result[i] = "notok";
      notok++; //to keep track of notok
    }
    else{
      result[i] = "ok";
    }
  }
```

Afterwards if you cycle through the result array you will see that all the values were saved. I find it simpler to have an int variable to know how many times the result was notok

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get the actual value within `dynamicvalue`: your test should be `if (dynamicvalue[i] != setvalue)`.

EDIT: And add a `break;` after the `result="ok";` instruction to break the loop, too.

EDIT 2: An above answer gives the corrected code using a `break`.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I forgot to add [ i ] in the question. Have updated the question.

Comment: @Stormbringer Posted too quickly, I forgot to say to add a `break`. Re-read my answer, please.

Comment: @Stormbringer Also why have you used `C++` as a tag? This code is clearly `C#`.

Comment: I cannot break from the loop as I have to compare all 50 values.

Comment: @SolvedGames What? No, that can be valid C++... If a `using namespace std;`  if present before...

Comment: @Wisblade You can tell that's C# because he has used `.count()` in his code. For C++, it is `.size()` / `.length()` for `std` containers.

Comment: @SolvedGames Oh, right, I mixed up with `QString` which also has a `count()` method, so it didn't triggered my mind to see that function instead of `size()`...

Comment: @Wisblade Mhm.. that's ok.